# Visual Studio 2013 Solution with Database project. Deploy Solution Does Nothing

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, localdb

I have a visual studio 2013 solution that contains 2 projects. One is a database project that is set to deploy to localdb. The other is a standard windows forms application that makes use of the database that is deployed to localdb. If I select deploy solution from the build menu nothing happens, but if I set the active start up project to the database project and run it with F5 it seems to deploy the database. Why does my database project not deploy when I select build -> Deploy solution?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the build config options have you got the "Deploy" box checked?

To get it you go to the Build->Configuration Manager menu.

Comment: Heya, I can see that my DB project has deploy ticked in the configuration manager. Also I have tried adding a project dependency on the Win Forms app to the DB project. This seems to make it deploy when I run the win forms app, but the Deploy Solution still doesn't want to work.

Comment: What do you get in the output window when you build, does it go through the steps of compiling the SSDT project (you should see something that says something like "Building the project model and resolving object interdependencies" - if you get that, do you also get something like " Deployment script generated to" - or a message to say that the deploy option has been skipped for the db project?

Comment: When I build I get this in the output window


`------ Build started: Project: Concerns, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  Concerns -> C:\Users\richard\Desktop\Concerns\Concerns\bin\Debug\Concerns.exe
------ Build started: Project: TFLConcernsDB, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
 TFLConcernsDB -> C:\Users\richard\Desktop\Concerns\TFLConcernsDB\bin\Debug\TFLConcernsDB.dll
 TFLConcernsDB -> C:\Users\richard\Desktop\Concerns\TFLConcernsDB\bin\Debug\TFLConcernsDB.dacpac
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
`

Comment: ok, I had a closer look - Deploy doesn't do anything in SSDT - use the Publish command instead. If you want to deploy the SSDT and the c# code you would have to add your own steps to the project files / msbuild script

Comment: Cool, I kind of had a feeling it might have been like that but wanted confirmation. Seems weird having build->Deploy do nothing whatsoever.

Comment: Yeah, i'll raise a connect item about it, even if all it did was a publish it wouldn't be so confusing!

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1213449 vote it up if you want to see a deploy also do a publish!